# How do I generate a random value between two numbers

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: generating random number in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/java-generating-random-number-in-a-range)

How do I generate a random value between two numbers. [Random.nextInt()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) gives you between 0 and the passed value. How do I generate a value between minValue and a maxValue

Comment: People find it easier to google or ask here than THINK.

Comment: considering we have two deleted, one incorrect, and one severely edited answer, it could be more difficult than it first appears to be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write a method like:

```
public static int getRandom(int from, int to) {
    if (from < to)
        return from + new Random().nextInt(Math.abs(to - from));
    return from - new Random().nextInt(Math.abs(to - from));
}
```

This also takes account for facts, that `nextInt()` argument must be positive, and that **from** can be bigger then **to**.

Answer (score 9):

`random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min` will do the trick. I assume you want `min <= number <= max`

Answer (score 1):

Example: Generating a number from 1 to 6 
Because nextInt(6) returns a number from 0-5, it's necessary to add 1 to scale the number into the range 1-6

```
static Random randGen = new Random();
int spots;
. . .
spots = randGen.nextInt(6) + 1;
```